# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "users.client.module.js" at path "_id"

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, angularjs-service

This is again another error I'm getting following through a MEAN stack development book. We've just added a new users module and a users service for allowing angular to use user information from an authenticated user. I'm getting a 500 error in the terminal for the following file

'/users/users.client.module.js'

This is the associated services file that is going with it. From what I've read this is a Mongoose error. Why is this popping up? I haven't even authenticated a user yet, this happens on page load for index.

Index Controller

```
exports.render = function(req,res) {

res.render('index', {
    title: 'Hello World',
    user: JSON.stringify(req.user)
});

};
```

Index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
    <title><%= title%></title>
</head>
<body>
    <% if (user) { %>
        <a href='/signout'>Sign Out</a>
    <% } else { %>
            <a href='/signup'>Sign-up</a>
            <a href='/signin'>Sign-in</a>
    <% } %>

    <h1><%= title%></h1>

    <section ng-view></section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.user = <%- user || 'null' %>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/users/users.client.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/users/services/authentication.client.service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/application.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/example/example.client.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/example/controllers/example.client.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/example/config/example.client.routes.js"></script>

</body>
```

Users Module

```
angular.module('users',[]);
```

Users Authentication Service

```
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [
function(){
    this.user = window.user;

    return {
        user: this.user
    };
}
]);
```

Edit - 2/2/2016 Re-ordered script tags in the view to this order, but still a no go.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/example/example.client.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/example/controllers/example.client.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/example/config/example.client.routes.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/users/users.client.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/users/services/authentication.client.service.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/application.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for the book leads to an error when using the `users.client.module.js` module. In my analysis, the static file /users/users.client.module.js loaded in index.ejs seemed to be interpreted as a server route /users/:userId leading to search a user in MongoDB with ID user.client.module.js. The issue has been resolved by placing the `app.use(express.static('./public')` statement at the beginning of setup (after the statement `var app = express();` for example) in the express.js configuration file but sure before de require routes statements.

NOTE: The author added this line in the [book's github repo](https://github.com/amoshaviv/mean-web-development/blob/master/Chapter%207/3285OS_07_01/config/express.js) (just before the closing, "return app"):

Comment: That was it! Thanks. It's unfortunate he didn't mention that this line would needed to be moved before the routes. The one thing that still peaks my interest though is why the input boxes now disappear after logging in as an authenticated user. But that I'm sure is a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue and solved if you comment on **users.server.routes.js** this code:

```
app.route('/users')
    .post(users.create)
    .get(users.list);

app.route('/users/:userId')
    .get(users.read)
    .put(users.update)
    .delete(users.delete);

app.param('userId', users.userByID);
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! Weird, I don't see that mentioned in the book anywhere. What exactly happened? Why did we remove these lines? Aren't this crucial to the the server side REST api?

Comment: Actually, I had to revoke that as the answer. It looks like by removing these lines it allows the app to run and the users to sign in, however Angular now has no way of access users from the server so when you sign in, the view no longer shows the input boxes.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried your code and could be related to the order you reference the scripts on index.ejs. Could you  try to do same order as the book does?

Comment: Hey Gran, I did try that as well with no luck. I changed the order as follows but still get the 500 error:
angular, 
angular routes, 
example.client.module, 
example.client.controller,
users.client.module,
authentication.client.server

Comment: angular.js, angular-route.js, example.client.module.js, example.client.controller.js, example.client.routes.js, users.client.module.js, authentication.client.service.js, application.js.

Comment: When you load index.ejs:
Check Nodejs command prompt console. Confirm there is no 404 for any GET.
Also open Developer>Web Console (Firefox) when you load the website to find any angular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Re-locating

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

didn't work for me. But simply renaming the `public/users` directory did. 
(thx Bsord@disqus)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I was running from `pm2`. After shutting down `pm2` and executing manually `node server.js` it worked fine. I don't know why...